# Is verbosity still faster than obscurity when including total filesize?

Tags: javascript, performance

I came across the following picture on Twitter lately:

[image]

I understand that the verbose check against undefined produces less VM bytecode and therefore runs faster but why do tools like uglifyJS produce code that looks more like the code on the right side (e.g. by aggressively removing any unneeded character).

Also, I know that this heavily depends on the JavaScript VM but I wonder if the performance benefit you get when writing implicit code still faster when comparing to uglified **and minified** code?

Here are my followup questions:

Are there examples where declarative code produces more bytecode and therefore runs slower?

Do uglifiers keep bytecode for different VMs in mind when minifying and obscuring code or do they just remove any possible character?

Is the performance benefit bigger than the added latency overhead?

Source: https://twitter.com/michaelhaeu/status/845003383153025024

Comment: The question is: Does it matter for YOUR page?

Comment: For the most part the performance hit is negligible. Each character contained within a JavaScript file adds a byte to the file size, so where `obj !== undefined` is 17 bytes, `obj` is only 3 bytes. The time it takes to download those additional 14 bytes is probably going to be much more of a performance hit than a 15% improvement of code which executes in less than 1ms anyway.

Comment: Beyond all I always advocate to *write what you mean*. Both code snippets do not do the same thing in different contexts. What exactly the machine code looks like is irrelevant if it doesn't do what you need it to.

Comment: If your minifier changes what your code is doing, change your minifier.

Comment: So this picture essentially is wrong due to the fact that they compare 2 different code snippets. One that checks for only undefined and another one that checks for a truthy value. So how can I Interpret this picture and why does it have so many upvotes?

Comment: Starting with the bad choice of wording (that is *not* "declarative" and the other is *not* "obscure"), I wouldn't put too much weight into this one. Yes, there's a point to be had here, but not a very major one.